# \left can only be used in math mode

Tags: tables, formatting

I'm encountering a problem with `\left` because the engine says that it must be used within `$...$`, but if i use the math mode everything screws up. Do you guys have suggestions on how to fix the problem?
This is the code

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
     W & X & Y & Z \\
     \hline
     0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{tabular}
$\quad$=
\left\{\begin{tabular}{l}
     $\nu(W) = 0$ \\
     $\nu(X) = 1$ \\
     $\nu(Y) = 1$ \\
     $\nu(Z) = 0$
\end{tabular}\right
$\null \qquad$ Each variable is a formula.
```

and this is how the result should be
[image]
Without any type of math mode the `Each variable is a formula` part looks like in math mode, while as soon as I use math mode the previous sentence is ok but the parenthesis becomes normal.
My goal is to get `Each variable is a formula` normal and keep the parenthesis as big as it is in the photo.
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `\left` can only be used in math mode but never do `x $=$ y` the whole expression is math, `$x = y$`

Comment: You probably want array not tabular as well as the cell entries are math

Comment: you need `\right .` where `.` gives the empty delimiter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a single expression so you just want to start math once and end it once, not around each letter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}



$
\begin{array}{cccc}
     W & X & Y & Z \\
     \hline
     0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
=
\left\{\begin{aligned}
     \nu(W) &= 0 \\
     \nu(X) &= 1 \\
     \nu(Y) &= 1 \\
     \nu(Z) &= 0
\end{aligned}\right.
$
 Each variable is a formula.
\end{document}
```