# Big curly parenethesis on the right of a table

Tags: tables, formatting

I recently asked help for the command `\left` and now I'm here to request your help with `\right`. I don't understand how I should use it, since output is as required but the engine gives me some errors.
This is the part of code I wrote:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$
\left\begin{array} {ccc|c|c}
    bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\
    \hline
    bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\
    bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\
    bla & bla & bla & bla & bla \\
\end{array}\right\} $ Blablabla \\

\end{document}
```

This is what I get (and it is exactly what I want):
[image]

But I still get `Unexpected \end{array} after \left`.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: exactly same answer as before but with left and right swapped, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697813/left-can-only-be-used-in-math-mode#comment1733447_697813

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `\left ... \right` pair acts on fences (a in `()` or `\{\}` etc). But ther is also the *empty* fence noted by a dot `.` (which is easily overlooked).

So for a construction where one only want to show one fence, the auto scaled version needs to use the empty fence

```
\left. ... \right\}
```